# not able to retrieve data by Query from DAPR state store using QueryStateAsync

Tags: c#, dapr

I am Using DAPR client to retrieve Data from Redis/Cosmos the Data is in Json Format. Using Key, i am able to retrieve but when i try to filter based on some value using Json Query it is throwing below error.
"

````
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="failed query in state store statestore: query index not found")
```" in postman.


daprClient.GetStateAsync("StateStore",Key) ------ working fine.
````

var query = "{" +
""filter": {" +
""EQ": { "ValueNode": "" + value+ "" }" +
"}}";

```
**daprClient.QueryStateAsync("StateStore",query )**  ---- not working


I tried configuring Query index in statestore.yaml 

- name: queryIndexes
    value: |
      [
        {
          "name": "ValueRefIndex",
          "indexes": [
            {
              "key": "ValueRef",
              "type": "TEXT"
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

and the below lines of code to retrieve

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;
Dictionary<string, string> metadata = new() { { "contentType", "application/json" }, { "ValueRefIndex", "ValueRef" } };

            var query = "{" +
                    "\"filter\": {" +
                        "\"EQ\": { \"ValueRef\": \"" + ValueRef+ "\" }" +
                    "}}";

            var queryResponse = await daprClient.QueryStateAsync<Product>(DaprStateStore, query);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is while saving to statestore.
It was saving in Hash format not in Json string, so while adding to statestore  below code will save in Json string so no problem while retrieving.

```
Dictionary<string, string> metadata = new() { { "contentType", "application/json" }};
await daprClient.SaveStateAsync<Product>(DaprStateStore,  "key",  JsonData, metadata: metadata );
```